# Generate fully qualified host names

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I need to fully qualify all hostnames that are not currently.

`H284Infa.txt` contains some fully qualified domain names and some that are not within // /.

`h284infalist.ps1` holds all the host names with their domain separated by an `=` sign.

I need to pull this list into `H284infa.txt` to fully qualify all IDs that are not and write the output to `output.txt`. Not all lines below are correct but this is where I am currently. On the second to last line I also need to command to pull data between the two documents.

```
$data = Get-Content "H284Infa.txt"
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "output.txt"
foreach ($line in $data)
{
  $var = (($var -split ("\\\\"))[1]) 
  $var = (($var –split ("\\"))[0]).ToLower
  if var "empty" If ($var -eq ".com")
  {
    if var If ($var -notlike ".com")
    {
      $data1 = Get-Content "h284infalist.ps1" | select-string $var
      $hostname = (($line -split ("="))[0]).ToLower()
      $fqdn = ($hostname + "." + ($line -split ("="))[1]).ToLower()
      $c=$line1.ToLower() -replace $var, $fqdn
      $stream.WriteLine($c) 
    }
    else {
      "pull line from file A to file B"
      $stream.close()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly (and sorry, you're rather hard to understand) you want to read a line from file A, do a regex match, modify the line if it doesn't match and then append the line to file B? If so, could you provide some example input and expected output?

Comment: Aside from the fact that your code is incomplete and couldn't possibly work: what is your actual question here?

Comment: File A is “H284Infa.txt”. It contains a list of both fully qualified and non-qualified domain names. An example of a non-qualified name is BDFTP025\\pfgdsmbank033\PrincorHSA. An example of a fully qualified domain name is BDFTP026\\pfgdsmbank033t.principalusa.corp.principal.com\TestInformatica\NAO. The “.principal.com” portion is what fully qualifies the address. File B is “h284infalist.ps1”. This document contains a list of all hostnames paired by an equal sign with its specific web address, which fully qualifies it. An example is pfgdsmbankfs001 = principalusa.corp.principal.com

Comment: Output of the two will be combined into File C: “output.txt”. I need to pull all pairs from File B to replace all non-fully qualified addresses from File A. The output will then be written to File C.

Comment: You mean you want to read a list of hostname-to-FQDN mappings from `h284infalist.ps1` and then replace matching hostnames in `H284Infa.txt` with the corresponding FQDN?

Comment: Yes and then write that output to output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$host2fqdn = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\h284infalist.ps1' | % {
  $hostname, $fqdn = $_ -split '\s*=\s*'
  $host2fqdn[$hostname] = $fqdn
}

(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\H284Infa.txt') | % {
  if ( $_ -match '\\\\(.+?)\\' -and  $host2fqdn[$matches[1]] ) {
    $_ -replace $matches[1], $host2fqdn[$matches[1]]
  } else {
    $_
  }
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\H284Infa.txt'
```